# jQuery Validation plugin custom validation method not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I know my question might be a duplicate, but I have tried every solution possible here but I still don't understand what I am doing wrong. As my code below shows, I am trying to validate a date entered using the jQuery DatePicker. I just need to know if the user chose a date if not do not submit the form but it still fires an error even when a date value is chosen, I am confused. Here is my code below, any help will greatly help me! Thanks

### Html

```
<input type="text" id="P.DateService" name="P.DateService">
```

### JS

```
$.validator.addMethod("dateValidation", function(value, element){
      var rett = jQuery.datepicker.ParseDate("dd-mm-yy", value);
      if(rest !== null){
        return true;
      }else { 
        return false;
      }
    }, "Date requise.");

   $("#form").validate({
      rules: {
        "P.DateService": {
           dateValidation: true
        }
     },
      messages: {
        "P.DateService": "Date requise";
      }
})
```

Comment: Is your var named `rett` or `rest`... please check your syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your custom validation, you defined `rett` as a variable an the compare `rest` in your `if` statement , so it will always return false.

Hope it helps.